# Nested case in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to write a SQL statement

- if TC is greater than 1 return 500
- if TC is greater than .5 return 200
- if TC is greater than .25 return 100
- if TC is less than .25 return 50.

I know it's a nested case, using MySQL

**EDIT:**
If table two has columns `Id`, `TC`, how do I use above to update the TC value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case when tc > 1 then 500
            when tc > .5 then 200
            when tc > .25 then 100
            else 50
       end
    ...
```

EDIT: Based on comments from OP

```
update YourTable
    set tc = case when tc > 1 then 500
                 when tc > .5 then 200
                 when tc > .25 then 100
                 else 50
             end
```

Comment: +1, no need for a nested case statement as long as the conditions are in the right order.

Comment: thanks, If table two column Id, TC, how do i use above to update the TC value

Comment: @user428862: I've added the update statement example to my answer.